# Get the coordinates and dimensions of individual characters in a rich text box

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, richtextbox, rtf

I need to traverse characters in a rich text box and obtain the exact position and dimensions of each character.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: This is quite tricky, the text in the rich text box is drawn using the Uniscribe API. Unicode text is not like an array of characters. If you would narrow your character set to western languages you could perhaps use the `GetTextExtentPoint32` function.

Comment: `EM_POSFROMCHAR` could be of some help.

Comment: Thanks. I will try both approaches and revert back soon. Both comments seem to be valid suggestions so you guys should post them as answers.

Comment: @demorge: You should post your comment as an answer to be accepted.